# Single quote in table name in a query c#

Tags: c#, sql, escaping, dbase

I am trying to run a query on a dbase IV table from C#. I am not all that experienced with C# and I have come to my wits end because my select statement fails because the table I am trying to query contains a single quote.

I am using an ODBC connection to connect to the table and that part works fine. I run a query on the same table if I rename it and remove the quote.

I have tried escaping it with a backslash, using 2 single quotes, and parameterized the query only to find out this doesnt work with table names.

The command text is as so and this is the root of the problem...

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM E4X'MAIN";
```

Please Help I am completely stuck and have spent days looking for solutions only to be thwarted time after time...

Comment: Try the following: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [E4X'MAIN]";`

Comment: @svick: By `improving` the edit suggestion you implicitly approved the edit while you actually removed all of it again. I think you should only choose that option if you actaully agree with the edit suggestion.

Comment: @H.B., actually, I rejected the edit, found out that that means I can't edit myself directly, clicked “edit” on Oded's revision in history which did what you can see: seemingly approved Ryan's edit and then reverted it in mine.

Comment: @svick: Then apparently one should not edit older revisions either while there are pending suggestions i guess. The waiting might be a bit annoying but it is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I have found a solution to my problem. If I structure my query like so shazam she works!!

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM \`E4X'MAIN.DBF\`;
```

Thanks for all your help hopefully this answer will help others stuck with horrible naming conventions

Reno

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [E4X'MAIN]";
```

?

**Edit:**

I've looked everywhere I know to look for an answer to this problem and I've found nothing.  The only thing I can say is that everyone seems to be in unanimous agreement that a table name like that is a *bad* idea. But I'm guessing that since you've spent this much time on it already, renaming the table permanently can't be an option for you. But if somehow it is, I suggest you take it.

Comment: Because I'm a moron :) Fixed.

Comment: I was hopeful there for a second because I hadnt tried the square brackets, but still no luck.

Comment: Yeah I know I am trying to build a translator that will pull data from an ancient piece of estimating software and insert it into a somewhat more modern MIS system running MSSQL. This is the second project I have tried to write in C# and both of them have run into serious issues this one seemingly impossible. I really appreciate your help regardless Tim... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is SQl SERVER? Oracle?

Tried

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM E4X'MAIN";
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [E4X'MAIN]";
```

?